# How can I solve - can not resolve symbol execute

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

[I had seen this error in this line:
 new JSONTask.execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6xmE.png)

I am developing an application creating a URL connection, JSON Parsing, Asintask. But I get an error, I was given an image.

given this error in can't resolve symbol execute.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  TextView tvData;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnHit = findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
     tvData = findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

    btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JSONTask.execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
        }
    });


}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer  buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line ="";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            return buffer.toString();


        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvData.setText(result);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
new JSONTask().execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
```

Instead of this

```
new JSONTask.execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
```

Comment: @NasirUddin not working means can you explain more?

Comment: @NasirUddin  Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)